# Java String Manipulation adding Hyphens between repeated Chars and returning a new string

Tags: java, arrays, string, char

Currently working on a program to manipulate a string passed in to a method. The program is to take a string find any repeated char elements and add a hyphen between them. I am getting an outofbounds error currently. For my code for instance my first variable i pass in is "Hello" the new returned string should be "Hel-lo". I am a newer programmer and would generally like to stick with the basic methods such as charAt() substring() and length(). Here is my code snippet. I am new to stackoverflow I hope my question complies.

```
public class SeperateDuplicates
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {

      System.out.println(seperateDuplicatesChars("Hello"));
      System.out.println(seperateDuplicatesChars("Bookkeeper"));
      System.out.println(seperateDuplicatesChars("Yellowwood door"));
      System.out.println(seperateDuplicatesChars("Chicago Cubs"));

   }

   public static String seperateDuplicatesChars(String str)
   {
      char[] arr = new char[str.length()];

      for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
      {
         arr[i] = str.charAt(i);
      }

      int counter = 0;
      for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
      {
         counter++;
         int temp = i + 1;
         if(arr[i] == str.charAt(temp))
         {
            counter++;
         }
      }

      char[] newArr = new char[counter];

      for(int i = 0; i < newArr.length; i++)
      {
         int temp = i + 1;
         newArr[i] = arr[i];
         if(newArr[i] == arr[temp])
         {
            newArr[temp] = '-';
            i++;
         }

      }

      String a = new String(newArr);
      return a;





   }
}
```

Comment: `return str.replaceAll("(\\w)\\1", "$1-$1")`.

Comment: If you want to do it without `String::replace()` note that to get a `char[]` from a `String` all you need is `char[] arr = str.toCharArray();` no loop required.